# Mysql dynamic query

Tags: mysql

I have two table in mysql 
one tbl_a which has one int column id,
second tbl_b which has one column song_ids in which data stored seapated by comma like 1,2,3,4

i want to select all id like this

```
select * from tbl_a where id in (select song_id from tbl_b)
```

but its giving me no record as its varchar
HOW to do it in mysql

Answer (score 2):

The proper way:

Change your database structure; it's not normalized. You should have a link table between tbl_a and tbl_b, where you have two fields: `a_id` and `b_id`. Then use a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_a
INNER JOIN tbl_link ON tbl_link.a_id = tbl_a.id
INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_b.id = tbl_link.b_id
```

The lazy, wrong way:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_a INNER JOIN tbl_b
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tbl_b.song_id, tbl_a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

that's wrong database design.
tbl_b must have 2 columns, a_id and song_id both of int type

for the query you have to give out more details about tables relation

Answer (score 0):

I would consider redesigning your tables before solving this problem.  Why dela with the headaches of comma delimited data?